# Plotting a function defined by a system of ODEs with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode45

I am trying to solve with MATLAB the first order ODEs system,

```
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}^{\prime }=-\frac{1}{t+1}x_{1}+x_{2} \\
x_{2}^{\prime }=-(1+e^{-2t})x_{1}-\frac{1}{t+1}x_{2}+\frac{e^{-3t}}{t+1}x_{3}
\\
x_{3}^{\prime }=-\frac{1}{t+1}x_{3}+x_{4} \\
x_{4}^{\prime }=e^{-3t}\left( t+1\right) x_{1}-\left( 1+e^{-2t}\right) x_{3}-%
\frac{1}{t+1}x_{4}-\frac{1}{t+1}x_{3}^{2}%
\end{array}%
\right. $$
```

I've defined the function:

```
   function dzdt=odefun(t,z)
        dzdt=zeros(4,1);
        dzdt(1)=-(1/(t+1))*z(1)+z(2);
        dzdt(2)=-(1+exp(-2*t))*z(1)-(1/(t+1))*z(2)+(exp(-3*t))/(t+1)*z(3);
        dzdt(3)=z(4)-(1/(t+1))*z(3);
        dzdt(4)=(exp(-3*t))*(t+1)*z(1)-(1+exp(-2*t))*z(3)-(1/(t+1))*z(4)-(1/(t+1))*z(3)^2;
        end
```

The time interval is `[0,100]` and the initial conditions are `z0 = [0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01]`.

With the `ode45` solver, I've used the commands:

```
>> tspan = [0 100];
>> z0 = [0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01];
>> [t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) odefun(t,z), tspan, z0);
>> plot(t,z(:,1),'r')
```

and I've obtained easily the graph of `z(1)=x_1`.

But I want to plot the function `f(t)=(t+1)*x_1(t)`, `t\in [0,100]`, where `x_1=z(1)` is the first unknown of the system. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use per element multiplication `.*`

```
plot((t+1).*z(:,1))
```